# How can I dynamically develop interactively against a HTML page in LightTable?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, lighttable

I have tried the LightTable and I can run Clojure commands just fine, but I can't figure out how to show a webpage within the IDE and execute ClojureScript commands against the DOM of the webpage interactively.

### Update

I will start to make a video series on Clojurescript, which will show how to use LightTable:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lX6isnBn6mY

Comment: see [this answer on a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14204874/547020).

Comment: Yes, I asked that question. I am able to execute clojurescript from LightTable but I do not have access to a DOM

Comment: Great, I'd love to see the answer too

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nES54tR_-U0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok, I figured it out in the end, and as promised I have made a few videos to show this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lX6isnBn6mY